# django template tag check if image exists

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've got a portion of my app that allows a custom logo.

Default object (and object view) state is no custom logo, but if one exists, replace the header with a custom logo navbar.

logo is a standard ImageField on co(mpany) model:

models.py:

```
class Co(models.Model):
      logo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

template:

```
{% if co.logo %}
    {% block navbar %}
        {% include 'templates/navbar_logo.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

I've also tried this with `{% if co.logo == None %}`, `{% if not ... %}`, `{% if co.logo.url %}` and trying to model the logic with `co.logo|default_if_none:""` but in instances where a logo isn't set the view throws:

`ValueError at /co/foo`
`The 'logo' attribute has no file associated with it.`

for... empty also doesn't work

```
{% for co.logo.url in co %}
...
{% empty %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

in django shell:

(with logo)

```
c.logo >> <ImageFieldFile: logo.png>
c.logo.url >> '/media/logo.png'
```

(no logo)

```
b.logo >> <ImageFieldFile: None>
```

is there a built in django template tag filter that will allow this condition to pass True only if the field has an image uploaded? otherwise don't load the nav block? thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by re-ordering the tags:

```
{% block navbar %}
    {% if co.logo %}
        {% include 'templates/navbar_logo.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'templates/navbar.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Use 'is not null'

```
{% if co.logo.url is not null %}
    {% block navbar %}
        {% include 'templates/navbar_logo.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: also in models.py set null=True

Comment: This does not work in newer versions of django, as block is always evaluated! See the other answer about re-ordering! (block needs to be outermost)